# Why does this PL/SQL not find a table?

Tags: oracle

I have 2 table DOQUANGDUC1 and DOQUANGDUC, in table DOQUANGDUC list table in database I need check:

declare

```
BEGIN 

    FOR x IN (select table_name,column_name  from DOQUANGDUC) LOOP
         INSERT INTO DOQUANGDUC1 (table_name,column_name)
         SELECT count(x.column_name),column_name FROM x.table_name GROUP BY column_name having count(x.column_name) >2;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

I run sql error

```
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 9, column 57:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 8, column 10:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I am sure two table already use.

Comment: Column and table names can't be taken from variables.You need to use dynamic sql (aka execute immediate) for your insert statement in order to pass table and column names from variables to statement

Comment: Apart from the point mentioned above what are you trying to insert. You are storing `count(x.column_name)` into a column `table_name`. Is it correct ?

Comment: And one more problem.  Your SELECT within the loop needs an INTO clause to specify where to place the result of the select.  That's because your are in PL/SQL, which has no way of interacting with the client or directly writing to a display device.

Comment: I need SELECT COUNT(column_name) from list table_name in doquangduc and insert into Doquangduc1 to then view the data ,so I think I'll use a loop

Comment: This is a good time to learn about Oracle context switching. There are hundreds of posts on the topic so I won't attempt to provide any. But Oracle context switching is one of the worst performing ways to do inserts. If you are determined to use a PL/SQL loop and an insert statement, look into the problems with context switching and how to avoid them.

Comment: Thank u, I need some suggestion from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

The cause of the error message is this line:

```
FROM x.table_name
```

This is telling Oracle to query a table called `table_name` in a schema called `X` and that does not exist. Hence the failure.

I think what you're trying to do is loop through a list of tables and columns and count how many values each column has, and insert the results into another table. You can't do that with pure SQL, you need to use dynamic SQL to format the statement.

```
declare
  stmt varchar2(32767);
begin
  for x in (select table_name, column_name from doquangduc) loop
    stmt := 'insert into doquangduc1(table_name, column_name, col_count) '
            ||' select '''||x.table_name||''', '''||x.column_name||''', count('||x.column_name||') '
            ||' from '||x.table_name
            ||' having count('||x.column_name||') > 2';
    execute immediate stmt;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Here is [a working demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cc86fe6c8bfd1f39d8f2a49f8aadcc0).

Note that I have changed the insert statement to populate **three** columns in `doquangduc1`: correct this to fit your actual table structure (which you haven't posted).

---

> It seems that the CMS_CIF_MUREX_NAME table has 292 records I add 1 duplicate record when running your command it shows the result column col_count = 293

My interpretation of your requirement is to count how many rows are populated for each column. Maybe that is not your actual requirement. Such misunderstandings are always a risk when you post a piece of code and expect us to reverse engineer your business logic. It is easier if you **tell us** what you're actually trying to achieve.

If you want counts for each distinct value in the column you can add a GROUP clause before the HAVING clause in my query.

```
'group by '||x.column_name ||
```

You may also want to add the value to the records inserted into `doquangduc1`, so you know which value has which count.

Comment: you need to add a 'group by ...' to your stmt, no?

Comment: @gsalem - no, because the other columns in the projection are string literals. Oracle is clever enough to know those are not going to vary.

Comment: It seems that the CMS_CIF_MUREX_NAME table has 292 records I add 1 duplicate record when running your command it shows the result column col_count = 293

Answer (score 0):

**Approaches to Inserting into a Table through an Implicit Cursor or a Select Statement**

Our Requirement:

We are going through the records in `doquangduc` and finding instances where the column_name appears more than twice.

Next, we are placing these records in another table, `doquangduc1`, while preserving the counts (placing them in `doquangduc1`).

Ultimately, these records are needed so they can be viewed.

---

Comments about this requirement:

It is not really clear that we really need to perform a transformation of the table, `doquangduc`, and then insert into another table to view the resulting records. This answer assumes this is necessary.

We create and execute DDL for tables needed first.

```
CREATE TABLE doquangduc
    AS
        SELECT
            table_name,
            column_name
        FROM
            user_tab_columns;
```

We create the table, `doquangduc1`, and make sure there is a column called col_count:

```
CREATE TABLE doquangduc1
    AS
        SELECT
            table_name,
            column_name,
            1 col_count
        FROM
            user_tab_columns
        WHERE
            table_name IS NULL;
```

We sort through the `doquangduc` table to identify scenarios you have identified.

```
   BEGIN
    FOR x IN (
        WITH qry AS (
            SELECT
                table_name,
                column_name,
                COUNT(1)
                OVER(PARTITION BY column_name) AS col_count
            FROM
                user_tab_columns
        )
        SELECT
            table_name,
            column_name,
            col_count
        FROM
            qry
        WHERE
            col_count > 2
    ) LOOP
        INSERT INTO doquangduc1 (
            table_name,
            column_name,
            col_count
        ) VALUES (
            x.table_name,
            x.column_name,
            x.col_count
        );

    END LOOP;
END;
```

---

As various people have commented, do we really need an implicit cursor to perform this insert into the table, `doquangduc1`, so that we can view the results?

We could just perform a INSERT INTO with a SELECT statement to more efficiently insert these records into `doquangduc1`:

```
INSERT INTO doquangduc1
    WITH qry AS (
        SELECT
            table_name,
            column_name,
            COUNT(1)
            OVER(PARTITION BY column_name) AS col_count
        FROM
            user_tab_columns
    )
    SELECT
        table_name,
        column_name,
        col_count
    FROM
        qry
    WHERE
        col_count > 2;
```

Comment: Why do you make a loop and insert lines one-by-one? You should better use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I agree with you that it's inefficient and I could have offered an alternate, more efficient solution. I got the impression the op was practicing the use of implicit cursors and needed to know how to reference them in a code block.

Comment: I need SELECT COUNT(column_name) from list table_name in doquangduc and insert into Doquangduc1 to then view the data ,so I think I'll use a loop

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - my interpretation of the Seeker's requirement is that they need dynamic queries on the tables listed in their first table. If so a PL/SQL loop is necessary.